# Expandable Cell numberOfRowsInSection with Section

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm having this trouble with expandable cells sections when using

```
return arrayUiText[section].nombre.count
```

on `numberOfRowsInSection`, only returns 1 cell and that's correct because it only have 1 number in the array, but my question is how could i return more than one because i have 3 different cells but returning is been a struggle for me as you can see my `arrayUiText` as multiples names in different arrays, I could achieve my goal just adding multiples names on 1 array, but i could only use 1 `SectionHeader` and that's not what i wanted to do nombre: `["dasdad dasda", "asdasdasda", "asdasdsa"]` like this.

I try to **numberOfRowsInSection** `return 3` but it collapses

```
var arrayUiText = [
    typeOfPasajeroNameLastName(isExpanded: false, pasajeroNumber: ["Pasajero 1"], pasajeroType: ["Adulto"], nombre: ["dasdad dasda"], apellido: ["asdasd asdas"], birthDate: ["24/05/1994"]),
    typeOfPasajeroNameLastName(isExpanded: false, pasajeroNumber: ["Pasajero 2"], pasajeroType: ["Adulto"], nombre: ["asdad"], apellido: ["asda asdasd"], birthDate: ["21/04/1994"]),
    typeOfPasajeroNameLastName(isExpanded: false, pasajeroNumber: ["Pasajero 3"], pasajeroType: ["Bebé"], nombre: ["asdas"], apellido: ["asdasd asdass"], birthDate: ["08/08/2018"])
]

extension PasajerosPaso2View: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if !arrayUiText[section].isExpanded{
            return 0
        }
    return arrayUiText[section].nombre.count  //this returns 1 i want returning 3

    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   
   
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pasajerosData", for: indexPath) as! PasajerosPaso2Cell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.tipoDeDatoTextField.text = arrayUiText[indexPath.section].nombre[indexPath.row]
        cell.tipoDeDatoTextField.delegate = self
        print("indexpath 0: \(arrayUiText[indexPath.section].nombre)")
        return cell
    }
    if indexPath.row == 1{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pasajerosApellidos", for: indexPath) as! PasajerosApellidosCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.tipoDeDatoTextField.text = arrayUiText[indexPath.section].apellido[indexPath.row]
        cell.tipoDeDatoTextField.delegate = self
        print("indexpath 1: \(arrayUiText[indexPath.section].apellido)")
        return cell
    }
    
    else {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "pasajerosBirthday", for: indexPath) as! PasajerosDateCell
        cell2.selectionStyle = .none
        cell2.tipoDeDatoTextField.text = arrayUiText[indexPath.section].birthDate[indexPath.row]
        print("indexpath 2: \(arrayUiText[indexPath.section].birthDate[indexPath.row])")
        return cell2
    }
    

    

    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.row)
    
    
}
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "titleCelll") as! TitleCell
    headerView.addSubview(headerCell)
    headerView.backgroundColor = .white
    headerCell.pasajeroNumber.text = arrayUiText[section].pasajeroNumber.first
    headerCell.pasajeroType.text = arrayUiText[section].pasajeroType.first
    let tapGesture5: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleExpandClose2))
    tapGesture5.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGesture5.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    headerCell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    headerCell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture5)
    headerCell.tag = section
    print(headerCell.tag)
    return headerView
    

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
```

}

```
@objc func handleExpandClose2(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Trying to expand and close section...")
    //delegate?.cerrarLista1(self)
    let section = sender.view?.tag ?? 0

    // we'll try to close the section first by deleting the rows
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    for row in arrayUiText[section].nombre.indices {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        indexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }

    let isExpanded = arrayUiText[section].isExpanded
    arrayUiText[section].isExpanded = !isExpanded



    if isExpanded {
        pasajerosTableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    } else {
        pasajerosTableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're returning `arrayUiText[section].nombre.count` which always equal to 1 based on your `arrayUiText`

You'd need to change your `typeOfPasajeroNameLastName` data structure to something like

```swift
enum Item {
   case nombre(values: [String])
   case apellido(values: [String])
   case birthDate(values: [String])
}

typeOfPasajeroNameLastName(isExpanded: false, pasajeroNumber: ["Pasajero 1"], pasajeroType: ["Adulto"], items: [.nombre(values: ["dasdad dasda"], .apellido(values:["asdasd asdas"]), .birthDate(values: ["24/05/1994"]))]),
```

then

`arrayUiText[section].items.count` will return 3 items